# Websocket connection works in IE and doesnt work in Edge

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am using default stomp.js file for creating websocket connections. Connection works fine in edge but it doesn't work in edge. It gives the following error.
error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.13/$rootScope/inprog?
p0=%24digest
at angular.min.js:12:20
at n (angular.min.js:2712:37)
at a.$$childScopeClass.$$childScopeClass.$apply (angular.min.js:2869:32)
at qtsLaunch.js:190:63
at angular.min.js:1830:25
at Q (angular.min.js:2544:57)
at Q (angular.min.js:2544:57)
at angular.min.js:2600:35
at h.$eval (angular.min.js:2859:32)
at h.$digest (angular.min.js:2818:56)

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://check-demo.internal/Rust/406/k4hocrzy/websocket' failed: 
 SockJS.websocket   @   VM27:1213
 SockJS._try_next_protocol  @   VM27:1150
 SockJS._didClose   @   VM27:1058
 SockJS.that._ir.onfinish   @   VM27:984
 EventEmitter.emit  @   VM27:148
 xo.onfinish    @   VM27:1948
 EventEmitter.emit  @   VM27:148
 that.xhr.onreadystatechange    @   VM27:801
enter code here




 (function() {
  var Byte, Client, Frame, Stomp,
    hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    slice = [].slice;

  Byte = {
    LF: '\x0A',
    NULL: '\x00'
  };

  Frame = (function() {
    var unmarshallSingle;

    function Frame(command1, headers1, body1, escapeHeaderValues1) {
      this.command = command1;
      this.headers = headers1 != null ? headers1 : {};
      this.body = body1 != null ? body1 : '';
      this.escapeHeaderValues = escapeHeaderValues1 != null ? escapeHeaderValues1 : false;
    }

    Frame.prototype.toString = function() {
      var lines, name, ref, skipContentLength, value;
      lines = [this.command];
      skipContentLength = (this.headers['content-length'] === false) ? true : false;
      if (skipContentLength) {
        delete this.headers['content-length'];
      }
      ref = this.headers;
      for (name in ref) {
        if (!hasProp.call(ref, name)) continue;
        value = ref[name];
        if (this.escapeHeaderValues && this.command !== 'CONNECT' && this.command !== 'CONNECTED') {
          lines.push(name + ":" + (Frame.frEscape(value)));
        } else {
          lines.push(name + ":" + value);
        }
      }
      if (this.body && !skipContentLength) {
        lines.push("content-length:" + (Frame.sizeOfUTF8(this.body)));
      }
      lines.push(Byte.LF + this.body);
      return lines.join(Byte.LF);
    };

    Frame.sizeOfUTF8 = function(s) {
      if (s) {
        return encodeURI(s).match(/%..|./g).length;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    };

    unmarshallSingle = function(data, escapeHeaderValues) {
      var body, chr, command, divider, headerLines, headers, i, idx, j, k, len, len1, line, ref, ref1, ref2, start, trim;
      if (escapeHeaderValues == null) {
        escapeHeaderValues = false;
      }
      divider = data.search(RegExp("" + Byte.LF + Byte.LF));
      headerLines = data.substring(0, divider).split(Byte.LF);
      command = headerLines.shift();
      headers = {};
      trim = function(str) {
        return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
      };
      ref = headerLines.reverse();
      for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
        line = ref[j];
        idx = line.indexOf(':');
        if (escapeHeaderValues && command !== 'CONNECT' && command !== 'CONNECTED') {
          headers[trim(line.substring(0, idx))] = Frame.frUnEscape(trim(line.substring(idx + 1)));
        } else {
          headers[trim(line.substring(0, idx))] = trim(line.substring(idx + 1));
        }
      }
      body = '';
      start = divider + 2;
      if (headers['content-length']) {
        len = parseInt(headers['content-length']);
        body = ('' + data).substring(start, start + len);
      } else {
        chr = null;
        for (i = k = ref1 = start, ref2 = data.length; ref1 <= ref2 ? k < ref2 : k > ref2; i = ref1 <= ref2 ? ++k : --k) {
          chr = data.charAt(i);
          if (chr === Byte.NULL) {
            break;
          }
          body += chr;
        }
      }
      return new Frame(command, headers, body, escapeHeaderValues);
    };

    Frame.unmarshall = function(datas, escapeHeaderValues) {
      var frame, frames, last_frame, r;
      if (escapeHeaderValues == null) {
        escapeHeaderValues = false;
      }
      frames = datas.split(RegExp("" + Byte.NULL + Byte.LF + "*"));
      r = {
        frames: [],
        partial: ''
      };
      r.frames = (function() {
        var j, len1, ref, results;
        ref = frames.slice(0, -1);
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
          frame = ref[j];
          results.push(unmarshallSingle(frame, escapeHeaderValues));
        }
        return results;
      })();
      last_frame = frames.slice(-1)[0];
      if (last_frame === Byte.LF || (last_frame.search(RegExp("" + Byte.NULL + Byte.LF + "*$"))) !== -1) {
        r.frames.push(unmarshallSingle(last_frame, escapeHeaderValues));
      } else {
        r.partial = last_frame;
      }
      return r;
    };

    Frame.marshall = function(command, headers, body, escapeHeaderValues) {
      var frame;
      frame = new Frame(command, headers, body, escapeHeaderValues);
      return frame.toString() + Byte.NULL;
    };

    Frame.frEscape = function(str) {
      return ("" + str).replace(/\\/g, "\\\\").replace(/\r/g, "\\r").replace(/\n/g, "\\n").replace(/:/g, "\\c");
    };

    Frame.frUnEscape = function(str) {
      return ("" + str).replace(/\\r/g, "\r").replace(/\\n/g, "\n").replace(/\\c/g, ":").replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
    };

    return Frame;

    })();

     Client = (function() {
     var now;

     function Client(ws_fn) {
      this.ws_fn = function() {
        var ws;
        ws = ws_fn();
        ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
        return ws;
      };
      this.reconnect_delay = 0;
      this.counter = 0;
      this.connected = false;
      this.heartbeat = {
        outgoing: 10000,
        incoming: 10000
      };
      this.maxWebSocketFrameSize = 16 * 1024;
      this.subscriptions = {};
      this.partialData = '';
    }

    Client.prototype.debug = function(message) {
      var ref;
      return typeof window !== "undefined" && window !== null ? (ref = window.console) != null ? ref.log(message) : void 0 : void 0;
    };

    now = function() {
      if (Date.now) {
        return Date.now();
      } else {
        return new Date().valueOf;
      }
    };

    Client.prototype._transmit = function(command, headers, body) {
      var out;
      out = Frame.marshall(command, headers, body, this.escapeHeaderValues);
      if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
        this.debug(">>> " + out);
      }
      while (true) {
        if (out.length > this.maxWebSocketFrameSize) {
          this.ws.send(out.substring(0, this.maxWebSocketFrameSize));
          out = out.substring(this.maxWebSocketFrameSize);
          if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
            this.debug("remaining = " + out.length);
          }
        } else {
          return this.ws.send(out);
        }
      }
    };

    Client.prototype._setupHeartbeat = function(headers) {
      var ref, ref1, serverIncoming, serverOutgoing, ttl, v;
      if ((ref = headers.version) !== Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_1 && ref !== Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_2) {
        return;
      }
      ref1 = (function() {
        var j, len1, ref1, results;
        ref1 = headers['heart-beat'].split(",");
        results = [];
        for (j = 0, len1 = ref1.length; j < len1; j++) {
          v = ref1[j];
          results.push(parseInt(v));
        }
        return results;
      })(), serverOutgoing = ref1[0], serverIncoming = ref1[1];
      if (!(this.heartbeat.outgoing === 0 || serverIncoming === 0)) {
        ttl = Math.max(this.heartbeat.outgoing, serverIncoming);
        if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
          this.debug("send PING every " + ttl + "ms");
        }
        this.pinger = Stomp.setInterval(ttl, (function(_this) {
          return function() {
            _this.ws.send(Byte.LF);
            return typeof _this.debug === "function" ? _this.debug(">>> PING") : void 0;
          };
        })(this));
      }
      if (!(this.heartbeat.incoming === 0 || serverOutgoing === 0)) {
        ttl = Math.max(this.heartbeat.incoming, serverOutgoing);
        if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
          this.debug("check PONG every " + ttl + "ms");
        }
        return this.ponger = Stomp.setInterval(ttl, (function(_this) {
          return function() {
            var delta;
            delta = now() - _this.serverActivity;
            if (delta > ttl * 2) {
              if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
                _this.debug("did not receive server activity for the last " + delta + "ms");
              }
              return _this.ws.close();
            }
          };
        })(this));
      }
    };

    Client.prototype._parseConnect = function() {
      var args, closeEventCallback, connectCallback, errorCallback, headers;
      args = 1 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
      headers = {};
      if (args.length < 2) {
        throw "Connect requires at least 2 arguments";
      }
      if (typeof args[1] === 'function') {
        headers = args[0], connectCallback = args[1], errorCallback = args[2], closeEventCallback = args[3];
      } else {
        switch (args.length) {
          case 6:
            headers.login = args[0], headers.passcode = args[1], connectCallback = args[2], errorCallback = args[3], closeEventCallback = args[4], headers.host = args[5];
            break;
          default:
            headers.login = args[0], headers.passcode = args[1], connectCallback = args[2], errorCallback = args[3], closeEventCallback = args[4];
        }
      }
      return [headers, connectCallback, errorCallback, closeEventCallback];
    };

    Client.prototype.connect = function() {
      var args, out;
      args = 1 <= arguments.length ? slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
      this.escapeHeaderValues = false;
      out = this._parseConnect.apply(this, args);
      this.headers = out[0], this.connectCallback = out[1], this.errorCallback = out[2], this.closeEventCallback = out[3];
      this._active = true;
      return this._connect();
    };

    Client.prototype._connect = function() {
      var UTF8ArrayToStr, closeEventCallback, errorCallback, headers;
      headers = this.headers;
      errorCallback = this.errorCallback;
      closeEventCallback = this.closeEventCallback;
      if (!this._active) {
        this.debug('Client has been marked inactive, will not attempt to connect');
        return;
      }
      if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
        this.debug("Opening Web Socket...");
      }
      this.ws = this.ws_fn();
      UTF8ArrayToStr = (function(_this) {
        return function(array) {
          var c, char2, char3, i, len, out;
          out = "";
          len = array.length;
          i = 0;
          while (i < len) {
            c = array[i++];
            switch (c >> 4) {
              case 0:
              case 1:
              case 2:
              case 3:
              case 4:
              case 5:
              case 6:
              case 7:
                out += String.fromCharCode(c);
                break;
              case 12:
              case 13:
                char2 = array[i++];
                out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x1F) << 6) | (char2 & 0x3F));
                break;
              case 14:
                char2 = array[i++];
                char3 = array[i++];
                out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x0F) << 12) | ((char2 & 0x3F) << 6) | ((char3 & 0x3F) << 0));
            }
          }
          return out;
        };
      })(this);
      this.ws.onmessage = (function(_this) {
        return function(evt) {
          var arr, client, data, frame, j, len1, messageID, onreceive, ref, subscription, unmarshalledData;
          data = typeof ArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && evt.data instanceof ArrayBuffer ? (arr = new Uint8Array(evt.data), typeof _this.debug === "function" ? _this.debug("--- got data length: " + arr.length) : void 0, UTF8ArrayToStr(arr)) : evt.data;
          _this.serverActivity = now();
          if (data === Byte.LF) {
            if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
              _this.debug("<<< PONG");
            }
            return;
          }
          if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
            _this.debug("<<< " + data);
          }
          unmarshalledData = Frame.unmarshall(_this.partialData + data, _this.escapeHeaderValues);
          _this.partialData = unmarshalledData.partial;
          ref = unmarshalledData.frames;
          for (j = 0, len1 = ref.length; j < len1; j++) {
            frame = ref[j];
            switch (frame.command) {
              case "CONNECTED":
                if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
                  _this.debug("connected to server " + frame.headers.server);
                }
                _this.connected = true;
                _this.version = frame.headers.version;
                if (_this.version === Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_2) {
                  _this.escapeHeaderValues = true;
                }
                if (!_this._active) {
                  _this.disconnect();
                  return;
                }
                _this._setupHeartbeat(frame.headers);
                if (typeof _this.connectCallback === "function") {
                  _this.connectCallback(frame);
                }
                break;
              case "MESSAGE":
                subscription = frame.headers.subscription;
                onreceive = _this.subscriptions[subscription] || _this.onreceive;
                if (onreceive) {
                  client = _this;
                  if (_this.version === Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_2) {
                    messageID = frame.headers["ack"];
                  } else {
                    messageID = frame.headers["message-id"];
                  }
                  frame.ack = function(headers) {
                    if (headers == null) {
                      headers = {};
                    }
                    return client.ack(messageID, subscription, headers);
                  };
                  frame.nack = function(headers) {
                    if (headers == null) {
                      headers = {};
                    }
                    return client.nack(messageID, subscription, headers);
                  };
                  onreceive(frame);
                } else {
                  if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
                    _this.debug("Unhandled received MESSAGE: " + frame);
                  }
                }
                break;
              case "RECEIPT":
                if (frame.headers["receipt-id"] === _this.closeReceipt) {
                  _this.ws.onclose = null;
                  _this.ws.close();
                  _this._cleanUp();
                  if (typeof _this._disconnectCallback === "function") {
                    _this._disconnectCallback();
                  }
                } else {
                  if (typeof _this.onreceipt === "function") {
                    _this.onreceipt(frame);
                  }
                }
                break;
              case "ERROR":
                if (typeof errorCallback === "function") {
                  errorCallback(frame);
                }
                break;
              default:
                if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
                  _this.debug("Unhandled frame: " + frame);
                }
            }
          }
        };
      })(this);
      this.ws.onclose = (function(_this) {
        return function(closeEvent) {
          var msg;
          msg = "Whoops! Lost connection to " + _this.ws.url;
          if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
            _this.debug(msg);
          }
          if (typeof closeEventCallback === "function") {
            closeEventCallback(closeEvent);
          }
          _this._cleanUp();
          if (typeof errorCallback === "function") {
            errorCallback(msg);
          }
          return _this._schedule_reconnect();
        };
      })(this);
      return this.ws.onopen = (function(_this) {
        return function() {
          if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
            _this.debug('Web Socket Opened...');
          }
          headers["accept-version"] = Stomp.VERSIONS.supportedVersions();
          headers["heart-beat"] = [_this.heartbeat.outgoing, _this.heartbeat.incoming].join(',');
          return _this._transmit("CONNECT", headers);
        };
      })(this);
    };

    Client.prototype._schedule_reconnect = function() {
      if (this.reconnect_delay > 0) {
        if (typeof this.debug === "function") {
          this.debug("STOMP: scheduling reconnection in " + this.reconnect_delay + "ms");
        }
        return this._reconnector = setTimeout((function(_this) {
          return function() {
            if (_this.connected) {
              return typeof _this.debug === "function" ? _this.debug('STOMP: already connected') : void 0;
            } else {
              if (typeof _this.debug === "function") {
                _this.debug('STOMP: attempting to reconnect');
              }
              return _this._connect();
            }
          };
        })(this), this.reconnect_delay);
      }
    };

    Client.prototype.disconnect = function(disconnectCallback, headers) {
      var error;
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      this._disconnectCallback = disconnectCallback;
      this._active = false;
      if (this.connected) {
        if (!headers.receipt) {
          headers.receipt = "close-" + this.counter++;
        }
        this.closeReceipt = headers.receipt;
        try {
          return this._transmit("DISCONNECT", headers);
        } catch (error1) {
          error = error1;
          return typeof this.debug === "function" ? this.debug('Ignoring error during disconnect', error) : void 0;
        }
      }
    };

    Client.prototype._cleanUp = function() {
      if (this._reconnector) {
        clearTimeout(this._reconnector);
      }
      this.connected = false;
      this.subscriptions = {};
      this.partial = '';
      if (this.pinger) {
        Stomp.clearInterval(this.pinger);
      }
      if (this.ponger) {
        return Stomp.clearInterval(this.ponger);
      }
    };

    Client.prototype.send = function(destination, headers, body) {
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      if (body == null) {
        body = '';
      }
      headers.destination = destination;
      return this._transmit("SEND", headers, body);
    };

    Client.prototype.subscribe = function(destination, callback, headers) {
      var client;
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      if (!headers.id) {
        headers.id = "sub-" + this.counter++;
      }
      headers.destination = destination;
      this.subscriptions[headers.id] = callback;
      this._transmit("SUBSCRIBE", headers);
      client = this;
      return {
        id: headers.id,
        unsubscribe: function(hdrs) {
          return client.unsubscribe(headers.id, hdrs);
        }
      };
    };

    Client.prototype.unsubscribe = function(id, headers) {
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      delete this.subscriptions[id];
      headers.id = id;
      return this._transmit("UNSUBSCRIBE", headers);
    };

    Client.prototype.begin = function(transaction_id) {
      var client, txid;
      txid = transaction_id || "tx-" + this.counter++;
      this._transmit("BEGIN", {
        transaction: txid
      });
      client = this;
      return {
        id: txid,
        commit: function() {
          return client.commit(txid);
        },
        abort: function() {
          return client.abort(txid);
        }
      };
    };

    Client.prototype.commit = function(transaction_id) {
      return this._transmit("COMMIT", {
        transaction: transaction_id
      });
    };

    Client.prototype.abort = function(transaction_id) {
      return this._transmit("ABORT", {
        transaction: transaction_id
      });
    };

    Client.prototype.ack = function(messageID, subscription, headers) {
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      if (this.version === Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_2) {
        headers["id"] = messageID;
      } else {
        headers["message-id"] = messageID;
      }
      headers.subscription = subscription;
      return this._transmit("ACK", headers);
    };

    Client.prototype.nack = function(messageID, subscription, headers) {
      if (headers == null) {
        headers = {};
      }
      if (this.version === Stomp.VERSIONS.V1_2) {
        headers["id"] = messageID;
      } else {
        headers["message-id"] = messageID;
      }
      headers.subscription = subscription;
      return this._transmit("NACK", headers);
    };

    return Client;

     })();

     Stomp = {
    VERSIONS: {
      V1_0: '1.0',
      V1_1: '1.1',
      V1_2: '1.2',
      supportedVersions: function() {
        return '1.2,1.1,1.0';
      }
    },
    client: function(url, protocols) {
      var ws_fn;
      if (protocols == null) {
        protocols = ['v10.stomp', 'v11.stomp', 'v12.stomp'];
      }
      ws_fn = function() {
        var klass;
        klass = Stomp.WebSocketClass || WebSocket;
        return new klass(url, protocols);
      };
      return new Client(ws_fn);
    },
    over: function(ws) {
      var ws_fn;
      ws_fn = typeof ws === "function" ? ws : function() {
        return ws;
      };
      return new Client(ws_fn);
    },
    Frame: Frame
  };

  Stomp.setInterval = function(interval, f) {
    return setInterval(f, interval);
  };

  Stomp.clearInterval = function(id) {
    return clearInterval(id);
  };

  if (typeof exports !== "undefined" && exports !== null) {
    exports.Stomp = Stomp;
  }

  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window !== null) {
    window.Stomp = Stomp;
  } else if (!exports) {
    self.Stomp = Stomp;
  }

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Connection works fine in IE but not in edge

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console of the developer tools, what is the response code for this connection? If possible, please provide a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem, which will help resolve the issue.